# How to get full width of wrapped span inside a td in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with fixed width of cells and having style "text-overflow:ellipsis". in each cell I have span with
 style "white-space:nowrap;".

My question is "how to check the span is wrapped or not" and "ow to get full required width of wrapped span inside a td"?

Comment: You mean, "how to check if the text is truncated or not"? Because with whitespace:nowrap, you know that it won't be wrapped. This is for tooltip purposes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jquery, you can get the width of an element by using [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/):

```
$(element).outerWidth();
```

The equivalent in JS is:

[`element.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth)

Comment: thanks. But I need in javascript. BTW, I have got full width by adding a temp element and assiging the innerHTML. After assiging the innerHTML, I have picked up the width and hide the element.